# How to get secondary nameserver

Tags: domain, ip, nameserver, dedicated-server

i was wondering how i can get a secondary nameserver with a different ip. I have a dedicated server, with already 2 IP adresses, but they are still on the same server. I need to have a IP adress on a diferent sever.

Do i need to rent another dedicated server to do this? Or are there any 'cheaper' methods to do this.

I want the namasevers to be ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com.

Not ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.someotherservice.com, i only want the two ip adresses to differ.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [EveryDNS](http://www.everydns.com/). I'm not sure if it would be possible to use it as ns2.mydomain.com, but you wouldn't need another server. It's not wise to use just one server for both nameservers as it's not redundant and you might get problems if your server goes offline just for a few seconds.

Comment: I used http://www.twisted4life.com/ for a secondary DNS for a while. Ideally your secondary DNS would be located on a different continent in case of severe network issues.

Comment: Hi, thank you both for you suggestions, i checked the links out and i saw twisterforlife was a free service. I was wondering tho if the service provides a name like nsx.twisted.com. Or can i use my own name with the service, nsx.mydomain.com.

Comment: You could only create an DNS A record for ns2.yourdomain.com pointing to the IP address of one of the nameservers of everydns or twisted4life, but it would stop working if they changed their IP address.

Why do you want to have your own subdomain for the secondary nameserver that much?

Comment: See http://www.twisted4life.com/dnsadmin.php?Menu=specs - if you have your own primary DNS server then you configure it to allow zone transfers to the twisted4life servers. The zone file contains your sub domains. It also specifies the primary domain name servers for your site (which would be your server and the twisted4life server).

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://freedns.afraid.org/ It's been online for quite a while now.